# Django - Docker python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, docker

I am using Docker first time in my life and with various tutorials I got to this stage here. All steps are finishing correctly, but after last step succeeds I receive this  error:

```
Successfully built 66717d9cdec1
Successfully tagged movie_universe_app:latest
Recreating movie_universe_app_1 ... done
Attaching to movie_universe_app_1
app_1  | python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
movie_universe_app_1 exited with code 2
```

And I don't know how to fix it. Here are my files:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

ENV PATH="/scripts:${PATH}"

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp gcc libc-dev linux-headers
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
RUN apk del .tmp

RUN mkdir /movie_universe
COPY ./movie_universe /movie_universe
WORKDIR /movie_universe
COPY ./scripts /scripts

RUN chmod +x /scripts/*

RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/media
RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/

RUN adduser -D user
RUN chown -R user:user /vol
RUN chmod -R 755 /vol/web
USER user

CMD ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
      - ./movie_universe:/movie_universe
    command: sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8888"
    environment:
      - DEBUG=1
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

uwsgi --socket :8888 --master --enable-threads --module app.wsgi
```

I tried to delete "volumes:" from docker-compose.yml but it is still not working.

Can please someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: As the error message suggests, the `manage.py` script isn't in the image: it isn't one of the things you `COPY` in.  (The `command:` override shouldn't be necessary either, but the `entrypoint.sh` script you quote [but don't run] will have the same error.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please elaborate? I tried adding "COPY ./manage.py /manage.py" but it didn't change anything. What am I missing?

Comment: If you `docker-compose run app bash` you'll get an interactive shell in a temporary container from the same image.  I'd expect you'll see a `/requirements.txt` file and `/movie_universe` and `/scripts` directories, but not any directly runnable Python files in the current directory.

Comment: Hey @Peksio Im having the same problem when using the same code as you did.  Did you find a solution for this?